# Different notions of width for multivariate Gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics, determinant

Given a multivariate Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ where $\mu$ is a real vector and $\Sigma$ an associated covariance matrix, I am looking for a good notion of width. There seem to be two options.

1. Trace-based widths:

The trace of the covariance matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues. The square root of the trace of the covariance matrix $\sqrt{\text{Tr}(\Sigma)}$ is an estimate of the expected RMS error between a sample and the mean (right?).

2. Determinant-based widths:

The determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues. The determinant of a covariance matrix in particular is a type of generalized variance. If $\Sigma$ has dimension $n$, then $\sqrt[n]{\det(\Sigma)}$ can be thought of one side length of a hypercube with volume equivalent to the generalized variance of the multivariate normal distribution.

Are there other notion of the width of Gaussian distributions?

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answerable because you don't explain what "width" is intended to mean, to be interpreted, or used in subsequent analyses.

Comment: My question was if there were other notions of widths for multivariate Gaussians. I think that's a clear question, and the response was useful.

Comment: For the reason I gave, it is *not* a clear question.   Whether the response was useful is nice but irrelevant for deciding whether any question is suitable for this site.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps one should define a "width" in a manner similar to the definition of "scale parameter." A scale parameter is a scalar assigned to probability distributions in such a way that if $c$ is a constant (i.e. not random) and $X$ is a random variable, then the scale parameter assigned to the distribution of $cX$ is $|c|$ times the scale parameter assigned to the distribution of $X$. Thus the standard deviation, the mean absolute deviation from the mean, the mean absolute deviation from the median, the median absolute deviation from the median, the range, the interquartile range, the mean range for a fixed sample size, are all scale parameters.

Similarly one might define a "width" as any function of the distribution with the property that its value at the distribution of $cX$ is $|c|$ times its value at the distribution of $X.$

You may have had that property in mind, since you took at $n$th root.

Then in addition to the two examples you mention, the maximum singular value with be a width. And probably there are others.